# Table element is cutting off while inserting

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-1.7

below is my html

```
<table id="myTable" class="dropdown">
 <thead> ........... </thead>
 <tbody class="myTbody1">
            <!--     insert here       -->
 <tbody class="myTbody2">
 <tbody class="myTbody3">
</table>
```

I need to insert the below html string right after the tbody, `myTbody1`

```
var html = '<tbody class="details" colspan="9">
<table>
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th> Col1 </th>     
            <th> Col2 </th>     
            <th> Col3 </th>     
            <th> Col4 </th>     
            <th> Col5 </th>     
            <th> Col6 </th>     
            <th> Col7 </th>     
            <th> Col8 </th>     
            <th> Col9 </th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody class="head">    
        <tr class="nestedRow">              
            <td> Data</td>      
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</tbody>'
```

I tried to do like below and it inserts at right place but it is cutting the first two tags tbody and table from the html string.

```
$(html).insertAfter($(this));
```

where `$(this)` equals `tbody.myTbody1`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As specified](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-tbody-element), `tbody` can only contain `tr` elements. Since the HTML you're passing is invalid jQuery just works with the valid portion that's created in the DOM.

To make a nested table like that you'll have to add a `tr` and `td` element as children of the `tbody` and put the inner table inside the `td`.

Comment: Hey Josh, if I use insertAfter, IE inserts the html into the tbody as a child, but I want to insert after the tbody, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest tables easily, using the JQuery provided by Shahil, but you need to surround the entire nested table in the 'tr' opening and closing tags. Your second code example should read

```
var htmlToInsert = '<tr>
<td class="details" colspan="9">
<table>
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th> Col1 </th>     
            <th> Col2 </th>     
            <th> Col3 </th>     
            <th> Col4 </th>     
            <th> Col5 </th>     
            <th> Col6 </th>     
            <th> Col7 </th>     
            <th> Col8 </th>     
            <th> Col9 </th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody class="head">    
        <tr class="nestedRow">              
            <td> Data</td>      
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
            <td> Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<td>
</tr>'
```

I would then use the JQuery `$('.myTBody1').html(htmlToInsert);`

Finally, make sure your `<tbody>` tags have matching `</tbody>` closing tags.

For more information, visit [JQuery API - .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)